# Getting the same range value in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, range

I've been trying to do my assignment but I've run into an logic error.I'm using Python 3.

```
print("Car Service Cost")
def main():
    loan=int(input("What is your loan cost?:\t"))
    maintenance=int(input("What is your maintenance cost?:\t"))
    total= loan + maintenance
    for rank in range(1,10000000):
         print("Total cost of Customer #",rank, "is:\t", total)
         checker()
def checker():
    choice=input("Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N):\t")
    if choice not in ["y","Y","n","N"]:
         print("Invalid Choice!")
    else:
         main()
main()
```

And im getting this output:

```
Car Service Cost
What is your loan cost?:    45
What is your maintenance cost?: 50
Total cost of Customer # 1 is:   95
Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N):    y
What is your loan cost?:    70
What is your maintenance cost?: 12
Total cost of Customer # 1 is:   82
Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N):    y
What is your loan cost?:    45
What is your maintenance cost?: 74
Total cost of Customer # 1 is:   119
Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N): here
```

I'm having my rank as 1 every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `main` calls `checker` goes into loop, calls `main` --> you're not looping at all, just restarting `main` in each *first* iteration of the loop (and you'll run out of recursion depth sooner or later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `main()` again in `checker`. You can just return (you can also use `break` if you put it in a loop):

```
def checker():
    while True:
        choice=input("Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N):\t")
        if choice not in ["y","Y","n","N"]:
            print("Invalid Choice!")
        else:
            return
```

If you want to break out of the loop in `main` if `'n'` or `'N'` is entered, then you can try returning a value:

```
def checker():
    while True:
        choice=input("Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N):\t")
        if choice not in ["y","Y","n","N"]:
            print("Invalid Choice!")
        else:
            return choice.lower()
```

And then check if it is `'y'` or `'n'` in `main`.

Edit:
If you don't want to use `return` you can just take out the loop and `else`, but this way you wouldn't be able to check if the user wanted to stop:

```
def checker():
    choice=input("Do you want to proceed with the next customer?(Y/N):\t")
    if choice not in ["y","Y","n","N"]:
        print("Invalid Choice!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `for` loop. From `checker()` you are calling again `main()`.

Instead of

```
else: main()
```

you should simply `return`.

---

I'm not sure you are doing what you intended in `checker()`.

Comment: We havent learned the return function yet and we are told that we shouldnt use it. Thank you